# как делать чтобы нажатием на какой то элемент он понимал это как комбинация клавивтуры на jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, клавиатура, click

Например когда я нажимаю на
Распечатать
хочу чтобы на клавиатуре автоматический сработала комбинация кнопок ctrl + p

Comment: `$('button').click(()=>window.print());`

Comment: Сработала, спасибо большое,   но вместо этого кода я написал так                            <a class="blu-basket" id="print_pdf" onclick="window.print()">Распечатать</a>